# 500 error on my website

Tags: php, html, mysql, http-status-code-500

I wanted to add to my website something like maintenance page, using PHP and MySQL. For example, if I'm adding some functions, I will set it in settings and it will display maintenace page instead of any page. But when I uploaded the whole code, it is showing me 500 error. Here is the code which will detect if maintenance page have to be shown or not:

```
if (isset($vsetko)) {
     header('include/maintenance_page.php');
     }
     if (!isset($vsetko)) { ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="sk_SK">
     <head>
...
Here is the website
...
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php   }?>
```

Can you help me with it?

Here's the whole code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'include/connect.php';
    include 'include/maintenance.php';

    if ( isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        //údaje o prihlásenom
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=".$_SESSION['user']);
        $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    }

    //Chybové hlášky podľa URI
    $url = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    if (stripos($url, 'error=')) {
        $errTyp = "danger";
        $errMSG = "Kód chyby neexistuje.";
    }
    if (stripos($url, 'error=1')) {
        $errTyp = "danger";
        $errMSG = "Na tejto funkcii sa pracuje. Prístup povolený iba administrátorovi.";
    }
    if (isset($vsetko) && $vsetko = 'true') {
        header('include/maintenance_page.php');
    }else{ ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sk_SK">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>DJ LiMix</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="slidedown.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/icon.ico"/>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php include('include/header.php') ?>
    <div id="wrapper" class="vrch page">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header vrch">
                    <?php
   if ( isset($errMSG) ) {

    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
             <div class="alert alert-<?php echo ($errTyp=="success") ? "success" : $errTyp; ?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
                <div id="zavriet" style="float: right;" title="Zavrieť upozornenie">&times;</div></div>
             </div>
                <?php
   }
   ?>
            <h3>Toto je úvodná stránka.</h3>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error iste ut quidem libero, et ipsa distinctio mollitia tempore debitis impedit dolores, minus ullam illum quis dolor numquam. Quidem doloribus, atque.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php include 'include/sidebar.html'; ?>
<?php include 'include/footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php   }
ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

This is in log:

```
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:43.722497 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140046944069376] [id +UeBylJIYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54183] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:43.722598 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140046944069376] [id +UeBylJIYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54183] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:43.722607 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140046944069376] (22)Invalid argument: [id +UeBylJIYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54183] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:44.551120 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140047372134144] [id 5/SNyuJ0MgI] [client 78.99.223.120:54184] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:44.551209 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140047372134144] [id 5/SNyuJ0MgI] [client 78.99.223.120:54184] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:44.551218 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140047372134144] (22)Invalid argument: [id 5/SNyuJ0MgI] [client 78.99.223.120:54184] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:45.137926 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140046679803648] [id HvyWykJjMgI] [client 78.99.223.120:54185] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:45.138010 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140046679803648] [id HvyWykJjMgI] [client 78.99.223.120:54185] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:45.138019 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140046679803648] (22)Invalid argument: [id HvyWykJjMgI] [client 78.99.223.120:54185] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:45.649078 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140046902109952] [id PMeeyhJHYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54186] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:45.649224 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140046902109952] [id PMeeyhJHYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54186] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:45.649237 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140046902109952] (22)Invalid argument: [id PMeeyhJHYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54186] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.064124 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140047319684864] [id PCClytJ3MgI] [client MY IP] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.064217 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140047319684864] [id PCClytJ3MgI] [client MY IP] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.064225 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22663:tid 140047319684864] (22)Invalid argument: [id PCClytJ3MgI] [client MY IP] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.415746 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140047867176704] [id vIeqygLaBwI] [client 78.99.223.120:54188] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.417215 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140047867176704] [id vIeqygLaBwI] [client 78.99.223.120:54188] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.417228 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22673:tid 140047867176704] (22)Invalid argument: [id vIeqygLaBwI] [client 78.99.223.120:54188] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.699343 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22667:tid 140047332194048] [id RNKuymJVYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54189] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.699487 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22667:tid 140047332194048] [id RNKuymJVYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54189] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:46.699496 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22667:tid 140047332194048] (22)Invalid argument: [id RNKuymJVYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54189] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:47.039864 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22664:tid 140047122396928] [id uOazyiJSYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54192] malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header: 
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:47.040108 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22664:tid 140047122396928] [id uOazyiJSYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54192] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Wed Nov 15 20:48:47.040127 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22664:tid 140047122396928] (22)Invalid argument: [id uOazyiJSYQE] [client 78.99.223.120:54192] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

Comment: not enough info

Comment: @Forbs what else do you need to know?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: okay, I'll check it and write here

Comment: `header` should have `Location:` if you are trying to direct the user. You also should `exit` after the `header` call.

Comment: No, I don't want to redirect them. I just want to include that page. But I Can try, that if I redirect them instead of including that page, if it will work

Comment: header should have "Location:" *if it is a redirect*. If you want to include the file the *include* it: `include('include/maintenance_page.php');`

Comment: Thanks, now I know the problem, it is with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 normally means something is wrong from your settings. But in this case its just bad syntax

Also I am no php expert but I have never seen header()

the correct syntax would be

```
     <?php
      $mMode = true;
       if (isset($mMode) && $mMode = true) {
         include('maintenance_page.php');
     }else {
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="sk_SK">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

         ...
      Here is the website
    ...
   </body>
 </html>
 <?php   }?>
```

Comment: is your include file inside a n include folder I also added the variable for you in case you have missed that.

Comment: yes, it is. But if it won't be inside, it will just display error, that the file was not found

Comment: Why would you put `isset()` after an unconditional assignment?

Comment: yes thats true u need to share the whole code as it is. Are you 100% sure your able to use other php scripts on the same set up as 500 normally means server error which is caused either by bad syntax .htaccess file on config miss match

Comment: "But if it won't be inside, it will just display error, that the file was not found" It will display en error alright. Internal server error, code 500

Comment: So are you trying to redirect to include/maintenance_page.php?

Comment: No, just to include that file

Comment: I tested it its working fine - you have some other issue

Comment: your error has something to do with your server being miss configured not the code being wrong. Think about what your changed today also make sure there is no space after or before your <?php tag

Comment: I only added this. And when I added this, it started showing 500 error.

Comment: what about other scripts if u remove it do they run.

Comment: I only added this script, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just stupid, I wrote

```
header('include/maintenance_page.php);
```

instead of

```
header('Location: include/maintenance_page.php');
```

to header. Now I use

```
include 'include/maintenance_page.php';
```

Sorry for not writing sooner :)